# the difference between those two className in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

what's the differance between `className={classes.specialButton}` and `className={"specialButton"}`

I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

`className={"specialButton"}` just literally adds the string "specialButton" to the html component. Btw it's deemed bad practice to use the curly braces when unnecessary. So rather use `className="specialButton"`.

`className={classes.specialButton}` adds whatever value `classes.specialButton` has. This is probably used in conjunction with some module or maybe even a constants definition somewhere like

```js
const classes = {
  specialButton: 'specialButton',
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const classes = {
  specialButton: 'specialButton'
}

<YourDivComponent className={classes.specialButton}>something</YourDivComponent>
```

or

```
<YourDivComponent className={'specialButton'}>something</YourDivComponent>
```

or

```
<YourDivComponent className='specialButton'>something</YourDivComponent>
```

Renders the same: `<div class='specialButton'>something</div>`